# How to generate .tlh file for the C# project

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop

How to generate .tlh file for C# project  which can be used by C++ Projects. Please help me

Comment: Does this work for you? Let me know so that I can provide additional information. https://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/728574-generate-tlh-tli-tlb

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to create the `tlh` file in C++. It's auto generated by the compiler once you specify the `tlb` file in the `#import` command.

You need to do following:

1) In your C# project, open the `AssemblyInfo.cs` (located in Properties directory).

Set `[ComVisible(true)]` (default is false).

2) Once you build the project, the tlb file will be created in the output directory.

3) In C++ code, use `#import "SomeFile.tlb"`.

Comment: No it's actually type lib generated  C/C++ header file.... But you have mentioned as .tlb file